# Detecting object collision by dragging. Trying to use the raycaster intersectObjects method

Tags: three.js

I am simply trying to detect when the lower sphere (the draggable one) is intersecting with the upper ones. I'm sure there's something I do not understand, unfortunately, nothing is crossing my mind on what.

```
<script src='https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js'></script>
<script>
window.onload = init;
// Global variables
var renderer, raycaster, mouse, 
scene, camera, sphere1, sphere2, 
sphere3, sphere4;

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function init(){
    // Get WebGL ready
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer = this.renderer;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // Get set                
    drawSpheres();
    // Go
    eventful();
    animate();
};

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

function eventful(){ // Where all events happen
    new THREE.DragControls([sphere1], camera, renderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false);   
};

function drawSphere(){ // Sphere geometry
    var geometry, material, sphere;
    geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return sphere;
};

function drawSpheres(){ // Draw four corners for the quadrant
    sphere1 = drawSphere(); sphere1.position.set(20, 0, 0);
    sphere2 = drawSphere(); sphere2.position.set(15, 23, 0);
    sphere3 = drawSphere(); sphere3.position.set(0, 22, 0);
    sphere4 = drawSphere(); sphere4.position.set(-20, 20, 0);
    scene.add(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4);
};

function onMouseMove(event){ // Calculate mouse movements
    // Pixel coordinates
    mouse.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
    raycasting(renderer, scene, camera);    
};

function raycasting(renderer, scene, camera){
    raycaster.setFromCamera(sphere1, camera); // Update the picking ray with the camera and mouse movements
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([sphere2, sphere3, sphere4]);
    for(var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++){
        intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
        console.log('Hit on: ', intersects[i]);
    }
};
</script>
```

The only thing I can think of is my usage of the intersectObjects() method or the setFromCamera(), but I am not sure. I think this would make sense, since it is updated on mouse move. How would I say: "I want the draggable sphere to be the raycaster, as I move it, and detect collision"? Or something simpler to detect when things collide.

For instance, consider the following:

```
window.onload = init;
// Global variables
var renderer, raycaster, mouse, 
scene, camera, sphere1, sphere2, 
sphere3, sphere4;

raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
console.log(raycaster);

function init(){
    // Get WebGL ready
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    renderer = this.renderer;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // Get set                
    drawSpheres();
    // Go
    eventful();
    animate();
};

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

function eventful(){ // Where all events happen
    new THREE.DragControls([sphere1], camera, renderer.domElement);
    window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false);   
};

function drawSphere(){ // Sphere geometry
    var geometry, material, sphere;
    geometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(3, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return sphere;
};

function drawSpheres(){ // Draw four corners for the quadrant
    sphere1 = drawSphere(); sphere1.position.set(20, 0, 0);
    sphere2 = sphere1.clone(); sphere2.position.set(15, 23, 0);
    sphere3 = sphere1.clone(); sphere3.position.set(0, 22, 0);
    sphere4 = sphere1.clone(); sphere4.position.set(-20, 20, 0);
    console.log(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4);
    scene.add(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4);
};

function onMouseMove(event){ // Calculate mouse movements
    // Normalized Coordinate System
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    raycasting(renderer, scene, camera);  
};

function raycasting(renderer, scene, camera){
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera); // Update the picking ray with the camera and mouse movements
    intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([sphere2, sphere3, sphere4]);
    for(var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++){
        console.log('Hit on: ', intersects[i].object.uuid);
    }
};
```

In this example, the raycaster **is** the mouse. You'll see the 'hit' message on the console, every time there is a mouse hover the spheres I've specified in the **intersectObjects()** method.

Answer (score 0):

if you aren't casting a ray from the mouse cursor, you don't need .setFromCamera().. you would just set up the ray manually.

You can use raycasting to check if one sphere hits another, or you can do a sphere->sphere intersection test like this..

```
var tmp = new THREE.Vector3();
function spheresCollide(centerA,radiusA,centerB,radiusB){
    var sqdist = radiusA+radiusB;
    sqdist*=sqdist;
    tmp.copy(centerB).sub(centerA)
    if(tmp.lengthSq()<sqdist)return true;
    return false;
}

//centerA and centerB are the vector3 positions of your spheres.. radiusA and B are the sphere radii
```

To do a raycast, you'll need to do something like the following, for each sphere:

```
rayCaster.ray.origin.copy(sphereA.position);
rayCaster.ray.direction.copy(sphereB.position).sub(sphereA.position).normalize()
intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects([sphereB]);
    for(var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++){
        tmp.copy(intersects[i].position).sub(sphereA.position);
        if(tmp.length()<(radiusA+radiusB)){
            intersects[i].object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
            console.log('Hit on: ', intersects[i]);
         }

    }
```

Comment: So what you are saying is that, as soon as I calculate the position of my draggable object, I can tell when it collides based on the position of the others?

Comment: How would I use the raycasting to check if one sphere hits another using these methods? I prefer this option.

Comment: So this is what the Raycaster page on threejs.org is implying? https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject

Comment: Ok, I'm making progress on this, but not quite there yet. Following the documentation religiously, I've replaced the onMouseMove by doing a Normalize Coordinate System calculation instead.

Comment: This allows the raycaster to follow in the mouse on mouse.set(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0); inside the raycasting function.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to get through this. There's something different about raycasting to a moving object. The idea behind ray casting is that a ray is being casted. For this example, the setFromCamera() method won't do, because the 'sphere' is supposed to be the object the ray(s) is(are) coming from.

```
    <script src='https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/DragControls.js'></script>
<script>

    window.onload = init;
    // Global variables
    var renderer, raycaster, 
    scene, camera, sphere1, sphere2, 
    sphere3, sphere4, dragControls;

    function init(){
        // Get WebGL ready
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        renderer = this.renderer;
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
        camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        // Get set                
        drawSpheres();
        // Go
        eventful();
        animate();
    };

    function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        raycasting();
    };

    function eventful(){ // Where all events happen
        dragControls = new THREE.DragControls([sphere1], camera, renderer.domElement);
        dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', onDragStart, false);
        dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', onDragEnd, false);  
    };

    function drawSphere(){ // Sphere geometry
        var geometry, material, sphere;
        geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(3,3,3,1,1,1);
        material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            wireframe: true
        });
        sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        return sphere;
    };

    function drawSpheres(){ // Draw four corners for the quadrant
        sphere1 = drawSphere(); sphere1.position.set(20, 0, 0);
        sphere2 = sphere1.clone(); sphere2.position.set(15, 23, 0);
        sphere3 = sphere1.clone(); sphere3.position.set(0, 22, 0);
        sphere4 = sphere1.clone(); sphere4.position.set(-20, 20, 0);
        console.log(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4);
        scene.add(sphere1, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4);
    };

    function onDragStart(event){
        console.log('on drag start');
    };

    function onDragEnd(event){
        console.log('on drag end');
    };

    function onMouseMove(event){ // Calculate mouse movements
        // Normalized Coordinate System
        mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
    };

    //////////////////////////////
    //////// RAYCASTING //////////
    //////////////////////////////

    function raycasting(){ // Blast rays like Cyclops or Superman, but only to measure proximity
        var sphere1Origin, // The 3D position of sphere1 when the page loads
        vIndex, // Vertex index
        sphere1VLength, // The amount of vertices
        dVector, // The directions the ray should be pointing to while it is moving
        raycaster, // The ray casting from a given point
        sphere1Origin = getUpdatedPosition();
        sphere1VLength = sphere1.geometry.vertices.length;
        for(vIndex = 0; vIndex < sphere1VLength; vIndex++){
            dVector = bindRaysToVertices(sphere1, vIndex);
            raycaster = raycast(sphere1Origin, dVector);
            collided = detectCollision(raycaster, dVector).hasCollided;
            if(collided){
                console.log('Hit!');
            }
        }
    };

    function detectCollision(raycaster, dVector){ // Determines whether there is/are (a) collision(s)
        var collisions, // Results of each collisions
        collided; // True/False
        collisions = raycaster.intersectObjects([sphere2, sphere3, sphere4]);
        collided = collisions.length > 0 && collisions[0].distance < dVector.length();
        return {
            hasCollided: collided,
            collisionsList: collisions
        };
    };

    function bindRaysToVertices(sphere1, vIndex){ // Make the geometry blast rays in all directions, while moving
        var lVertex, // The re-calculated (updated) vertices for the moving object
        gVertex, // The complete representation of the re-calculated (updated) vertices
        dVector; // The directions the ray should be pointing to while it is moving
        lVertex = sphere1.geometry.vertices[vIndex].clone();
        gVertex = lVertex.applyMatrix4(sphere1.matrix);
        dVector = gVertex.sub(sphere1.position);
        return dVector;
    };

    function getUpdatedPosition(){
        var sphere1Origin, // The 3D position of sphere1 when the page loads
        sphere1Origin = sphere1.position.clone();
        return sphere1Origin;
    };

    function raycast(sphere1Origin, dVector){
        // Make the sphere cast the ray, through its vertices, 
        // while moving, using a Normalized Coordinate System
        return new THREE.Raycaster(sphere1Origin, toNCS(dVector));
    };

    function toNCS(dVector){ // To Normalize Coordinate System
        return dVector.clone().normalize();
    };

</script>
```

Following [Stemkoski](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Collision-Detection.html) example, I've decided to use cubes as wireframes, and should there be a need to have a sphere, the cube should be within it. Otherwise it will be computationally expensive to have a sphere blasting rays like the Sun for proximity detection purposes.